Insulating rafters on 1920s home
My home has 2x6 rafters with 24" spacing.  The roof style is most similar to a Cape Cod house.  The house was built in 1920 and has no insulation.
I bought the home a few months ago and have the 2nd floor and attic completely ripped apart.  I'm planning to insulate all the second floor walls with rockwool.  I would like to also insulate the rafters with rockwool.  The 2x6 rafters would allow me to use R-23 rockwool, but I would like to leave an air-gap between the insulation and roof for ventilation.
Would it be a bad idea to just use R-15 rockwool for the rafters, allowing for a 2" air gap between the insulation and roof?  The roof has a ridge vent.  The house is on Long Island, NY.
Thank you.

"A bad idea" isn't something we can assess for you here. Opinion questions are off topic.  Please see the [help]. That said, you don't need 2" for an air gap. Half an inch is enough if you can be sure it'll stay open. Your ceiling should have at least as much insulation as your walls. Around here it's more than twice, in proportion.

Thanks @isherwood.  I wasn't necessarily aiming for a 2" air gap; R-15 is just the largest thickness rockwool I could do while having an air gap (I think).  Perhaps I can do as crip659 says and just pad out the rafters a bit and use R-23.

1920s 2x6s will be wider than todays 2x.  They are very close to actual 2 inch, compared to 1.5 inch of today.  Should not make enough difference for adding insulation.

What provisions are you making to get rid of the heat accumulating in the air space during the summer? Will  your design include vented soffits and ridge vents? Vapor barriers?

What are your ground snow loads like there? You may need the air gap next to the sheathing to control ice damming

@DelphicOracle -- an attic that's been brought "inside" with insulation and air sealing will generally be air conditioned as well

How do you plan to maintain this 2" gap?

To maintain the 2" gap I was planning to build baffles with 1" foam board.
We haven't gotten much snow lately, but actually did the last few days.  Did have some icicles coming off the front of the roof.

Although I do have a ridge vent, it seems as though I don't have vented soffits. Not sure why the previous owner did a ridge vent with no means for air intake.  Also many of the rafters begin in a 'valley' with no access to the soffit, so it seems like properly venting this roof will be challenging.  Considering just doing a hot roof with no air gap and R-23 rockwool directly against the roof sheating.
